# mpdf. создание нескольких файлов подряд

Tags: pdf, mpdf

Задача создать подряд 2 файла pdf с разным содержанием
Попробовал так:

```
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html, 2);
$mpdf->Output($file, 'F');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html1, 2);
$mpdf->Output($file1, 'F');
```

Первый нормально записало, во второй засунуло первый и нет намека на $html1. Пробовал искать очистку файла или закрытие не нашел. Подскажите плиз что не вижу.

Comment: `$mpdf->WriteHTML($html, 2, true, true)`
так не пробовали?

Comment: добавил.. тоже самое выдает

Comment: Ну тогда топорно. Создавайте еще один обьект, `$mpdf2 = new mPDF();` либо воспользуйтесь `$mpdf2 clone $mpdf;` если там множество логики до вывода идёт

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант 1

```
function SavePDF($html, $file){
    $mpdf = new mPDF();
    //Тут остальная логика
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html, 2);
    $mpdf->Output($file, 'F');
}

for($i=1;$i<5;$i++){
    SavePDF("<div>Hello</div>", __DIR__ . '/report_' . time() . '.pdf');
}
```

Вариант 2

```
$mpdf = new mPDF();
//Тут остальная логика

for($i=1;$i<5;$i++){
    $clonedMpdf clone $mpdf;
    $mpdf->WriteHTML("<div>Hello</div>", 2);
    $mpdf->Output(__DIR__ . '/report_' . time() . '.pdf', 'F');
    unset($clonedMpdf);  
}
```

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mpdf/mpdf/development/src/Mpdf.php
Вы же эту версию используете?
Покопавшись в коде заметил эти методы

```
$mpdf->Reset();
$mpdf->DeletePages(0);
```

Возможно они помогут.

Comment: методы не подошли

Comment: попробую сейчас с клонированием класса

Comment: клон сработал но сам html из файла пропал.. записал как текст

Comment: А первый вариант?

Comment: ситуация такая.. у меня есть класс который использует пространство имен. внутри метода если вызвать new mPDF(); то говорит что нет такого класса. Я в файле где вызывается метод класса в параметрах передал два инициализированных копии mPDF с разными переменными и пошло

Comment: но это это костыль..

Comment: В общем решено: использовал первый метод только чтобы создать экземпляр класса вне пространства имен использовал трюк new \mPDF();